# Get default background color

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have created a `TabBar` with three items.

```
enum TabItem : CaseIterable {
    case market
    case interest
    case wallet
}

struct TabBar: View {
    
    @State var tappedItem: TabItem = .market
    let tappedBackground = Color.primaryColor.opacity(0.2)
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TabBarItem(icon: "aqi.medium")
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.tappedItem = .market
                }
                .background(self.tappedItem == .market ? tappedBackground : Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .animation(.linear, value: tappedItem)
                
            TabBarItem(icon:"list.bullet.rectangle.portrait")
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.tappedItem = .interest
                }
                .background(self.tappedItem == .interest ? tappedBackground : Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .animation(.linear, value: tappedItem)
                
            
            TabBarItem(icon: "wallet.pass")
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.tappedItem = .wallet
                }
                .background(self.tappedItem == .wallet ? tappedBackground : Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(20)
                .animation(.linear, value: tappedItem)
        }
    }
    
}
```

The tapped item will change the background color to `Color.primaryColor.opacity(0.2)` and all others to `Color.white`.

Instead of `Color.white` how to get the default system background color?

Comment: You could try `nil` or `Color.clear` instead of `Color.white`, to allow the underlying background to show through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Color(uiColor:)` initialiser, i.e.

```
Color(uiColor: .systemBackground)
```